# Nesting window functions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

From time to time I'm fiddling around with SQL Server and I get an error akin to
`Can't use a window function on an aggregate`.  Which is frustrating because I have SQL Server 2008 and I know that 2012 affords better window function functionality and I use them a lot.  However, from time to time I do something like

```
select   me.patid
        ,COUNT(*) as eligibilityGapsNo
        ,COUNT(*) over(partition by count(*)) 
from memberEligibility as me
group by me.patid
```

and this works fine.  I assume is it's because I'm already grouping by me.patid but does anyone have a clearer idea of when you can nest window functions like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not nesting window functions here.  You are nesting an aggregation function `count(*)` with a window function `count(*) over`.

You can nest aggregation functions in window functions.  And, I do it.  However, I find it clearer to write this as a subquery, because nested aggregation functions just "don't look right" to me:

```
select patid, eg, count(*) over (partition by egcnt)
from (select me.patid, count(*) as egcnt
      from memberEligibility me
      group by me.patid
     ) t
```